# How To move or rearrange elements with constant velocity or speed from one part of the screen to other when the window is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

want to rearrange my elements on window resize. but will doing i want to graphically show users that the elements are moving and rearranging them self to the new size.

for example please resize this given link in you browser and observe
 - [An Example](http://tympanus.net/Development/Stapel/index3.html)

Comment: What is the problem with the script that powers the demo you provided (https://github.com/codrops/Stapel)? Also, check out http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: the problem is it uses "top" and "right" HTML proporties to re arrange elements. which is not a good practice and also not a generic solution.

Comment: How come it is not a good practice? As far as I know it is the only way of animating movement of HTML elements. If you think it is not generic try nesting a container with `position:absolute` inside a container with `position:relative`.

Comment: @pckill i understand that the basics of all the transform is position. but imagine if we had to implement a solution any given website which has dynamic html markup and a well defined css markup which cannot be much tampered with then using css top might not be a good idea.

right now i am using top and right ptoporties to deal with the problem but still in need of a better solution